# which scope should I select for using wercker auto deploy my github pages?

Tags: github-pages, wercker, hugo

I'm a blog rookie, following with the guide of 'auto deploy with wercker' from https://gohugo.io/tutorials/automated-deployments/, I don't know which scope should I choose

the guide didn't mentioned it

[here's the list of scopes from github](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rusyH.png)

Thanks first !

Answer (score 0):

The `repo` permission should be enough. The token more or less just needs to be able to push new commits for the `gh-pages` branch for you.

Answer (score 0):

After wercker created your build let's say on the master branch, you can trigger the deployment with https://github.com/leipert/step-git-push and push it to the gh-pages branch:

`deploy:
  steps:
   - install-packages:
     packages: git ssh-client
   - leipert/git-push:
      gh_oauth: $GIT_AUTH
      repo: gh-username/repo-name
      branch: gh-pages
      basedir: your-created-folder`

Whereas the $GIT_AUTH key is set in the Environment variables. Just copy the generated key from your Personal access tokens available under your Github Profile personal settings with Full control of private repositories.